# Disable text/input field in React & Nextjs depending on Dropdown Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, react-forms

I'm new to React and trying to disable an input field when the dropdown value is selected as "No" and enable when `Yes`. I'm using React, Next Js, React-bootstrap & formik.

```
function Input(){
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
 const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = React.useState('');

function handleClick() {
            if (radioValue === "Yes") {
                console.log('Text Enabled')
            } else {
                setDisabled(!disabled);
                console.log('Text disabled')
            }

        }

return(

<div>

<Form>
     
    <Form.Group controlId="usage_ppe" as={Col}>
        <Form.Label className="required-field font-Montserrat">{getTranslatedText('Usage')}</Form.Label>
           <Col className="p-0">
             <Dropdown
                  className="px-4 py-2 bg-green-1"
                  as="select"
                  value={radioValue}
                  onChange={e => {
                 setRadioValue(e.target.value);
                  }}
               >
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </Dropdown>
          </Col>
          {errors.usage_ppe && touched.usage_ppe && <p>{errors.usage_ppe}</p>}
  </Form.Group>


   <Form.Group controlId="usage_of_ppe_byWorkers" as={Col} 
                disabled={disabled} 
             onClick={handleClick}

/>

       <Form.Label className="font-Montserrat" >{getTranslatedText('If Yes, Enable Input')}</Form.Label>
               <Form.Control
                 type="text"  
                  className={errors.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers && touched.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers && 'has-error'}                                
                 name="usage_of_ppe_byWorkers"
                 placeholder="If Yes, Usage of PPE by STP"
                 onChange={handleChange}
                 onBlur={handleBlur}
                 value={values.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers || ""}
              />
              {errors.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers && touched.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers &&
               <p>{errors.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers}</p>}
   </Form.Group>
</Form>
</div>
)

}
```

Where am I going wrong here, it also logs the value `Yes` in the `handleClick` function, When we select the dropdown value as `Yes` It won't disable the text input that I've next to it. I'm confused about mapping the value. I don't understand What am I doing wrong here!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add disabled in `Form.Control` section? And you can determine the disable status by `radioValue == 'No'`. That's, `<Form.Control disabled={radioValue == 'No'} ... ... />`

Answer (score 2):

Form.Group is not intended to work as a standalone Input Component.
You want to have more Inputs inside a unique controller, and for this with react bootstrap you use the fieldset tag.

example with disable prop with disable:

```
    <fieldset disabled={disabled}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
          <Form.Label htmlFor="disabledTextInput">Disabled input</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control id="disabledTextInput" placeholder="Disabled input" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
          <Form.Label htmlFor="disabledSelect">Disabled select menu</Form.Label>
          <Form.Select id="disabledSelect">
            <option>Disabled select</option>
          </Form.Select>
        </Form.Group>
      <fieldset/>
```

---

You can also try to add the `disabled` directly inside Form.Control tag

full code should be:

```
   <Form.Group controlId="usage_of_ppe_byWorkers" as={Col} 
                disabled={disabled} 
             onClick={handleClick}

/>

       <Form.Label className="font-Montserrat" >{getTranslatedText('If Yes, Enable Input')}</Form.Label>
               <Form.Control
                 type="text"  
                  className={errors.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers && touched.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers && 'has-error'}                                
                 name="usage_of_ppe_byWorkers"
                 placeholder="If Yes, Usage of PPE by STP"
                 onChange={handleChange}
                 onBlur={handleBlur}
                 value={values.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers || ""}
                 disabled={disabled}
              />
              {errors.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers && touched.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers &&
               <p>{errors.usage_of_ppe_byWorkers}</p>}
   </Form.Group>
```

thanks

Comment: @Mahijendra I'm happy:) you can mark this as answered then!

Comment: It's working fine for the first time when I select the value as 'Yes', And when I change it back from 'NO' to 'YES' It's not working. What I meant to say is its behavior is pretty much unpredictable. I believe the problem is with the state value here. Do you happen to know about this?

Comment: Hi Mahijendra can you try like this, is also easier to read: disabled={radioValue === 'No' ? true : false}  so you are saying directly with ternary condition if radioValue is equal to No disable the Form